# Отрисовка скелета объекта поверх оригинального изображения

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Допустим у меня есть объект. Мне нужно найти его скелет, а затем отрисовать его поверх исходного изображения. Например вот:

[image]

С помощью каких инструментов OpenCV я могу это сделать? Использую Qt на C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаете скелет, например как-то так: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html
   (дело в том что в OpenCV нет встроенной функции для поиска скелета) или смотрите как это сделано в исходниках функции bwmorph() из Gnu Octave.
2. bitwise_xor от исходника и скелета.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! я попробовал использовать данный алгоритм но получил ошибку, связанную с bitwise_or. выглядит она следующим образом: Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::binary_op. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее можно решить?

Comment: Разберитесь какого размера у вас картинка и ее скелет. Какого типа uint8 или др., число каналов. Это все должно совпадать.